# putting binary data python sharemy3d

Tags: python, curl, put

I'm working with [ShareMy3D API](http://sharemy3d.com) and came across a problem.

> I have a file upload link and need to execute
>
> ```
> curl -X PUT -T - "[UPLOAD_URL]" < PATH_TO_LOCAL_FILE
> ```

---

My specific CURL command:

```
curl -X PUT -T - https://storage.googleapis.com/sharemy3d-central-us-1-produc‌​tion/alotofstuff < /home/max/Documents/file.obj
```

After I execute it I always get:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: <
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

Are there other ways to PUT **binary** files?

Comment: Please can you show the specific CURL command that you are using that's not working. (Change any URLs to 'example.com' if you wish.)

Comment: Hello, @DaveP. It's `curl -X PUT -T - https://storage.googleapis.com/sharemy3d-central-us-1-production/alotofstuff
 < /home/max/Documents/file.obj`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was execute `curl -T file.obj https://example.com`. 
 With `-T` (same as `--upload-file`) curl will use `PUT` for `HTTP`